# Why is the first line of a file note read with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

I guess this will sound crazy, but I am reading from a file, and it seems like it skips the first line of the file.

What is going on?

Here is the source:

```
    private void loadFile(String fileNPath)
    {
        StringBuilder currentFileContents = new StringBuilder();
        CharBuffer contentsBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(65536);

        int status=0;
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNPath));

            while(status!=-1)
            {
                status=in.read(contentsBuffer);
                currentFileContents.append(contentsBuffer);
                contentsBuffer.clear();
            }

            System.out.println(currentFileContents.toString());
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException n)
        {
            //Should be imposible
        }
        catch(IOException n)
        {
            n.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }
```

It must be something I am over looking.

I copied and pasted the exact source, so I hope this happens for you also.

Thanks,
caalip

Comment: I only getthe second line of the file, and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use  FileUtils.[readFileToString](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29)(file) which does this in one line.

However, when I run **your** code on a text file I see every line. I suspect the problem is not with your code.

Comment: You mean the apache commons FileUtils?

Comment: Yes, I have added a link and corrected the name of the method.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason you're reading the file the way you are?

You're using parent class methods (`BufferedReader` has no `read(CharBuffer)` method, for example) and also ... the `CharBuffer` itself is a bit overkill. I suspect the actual problem is you're not using it correctly (usually you flip and drain Buffer objects, but I'd have to poke more to see how this ends up manipulating it)

All you need to do to read a file is:

```
StringBuilder currentFileContents = new StringBuilder();
try
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNPath));
    String line = null;
    while( (line = in.readline()) != null )
    {
        currentFileContents.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(currentFileContents.toString());
}
catch(FileNotFoundException n)
{
    //Should be imposible
}
catch(IOException n)
{
    n.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Comment: I think reading the data in one at a time is probably slower.

Comment: Um ... yeah... That's called "premature optimization", and probably incorrect. That's why you use a BufferedReader in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit bizarre. Try changing your try block to:

```
try
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNPath));

        status=in.read(contentsBuffer.array(), 0, 65536);
        currentFileContents.append(contentsBuffer);

        System.out.println(currentFileContents.toString());
    }
```

I haven't run this code, but give it a shot.

UPDATE: I ran your code and encountered the problem you described. I ran the code with my revision and it works.

Comment: but what if the file size is too large ? will this logic works ? i think what you are doing is reading the file from 0 to 65536. But what if the size si more than that ?

Comment: I simply matched how many characters were allocated in the CharBuffer to how many characters should be read. If the file is larger, then this method is not appropriate.

Comment: what is the problem with looping in while ?? do u have any idea ?

Comment: The problem with the while loop is that it reads the file into the buffer twice. The reason for this is that the "read" method called in the problem code actually reads the contents until it encounters the end of the file. So what happens is "status" is assign the number of characters. Then the StringBuilder is loaded. The while loop is still valid, so it happens again. The "status" is assigned to -1 this time sine the end of the file has been reached, but the buffer is unchanged. The StringBuilder is again loaded with the file. When printed, the string is too large to print as intended.

Comment: `So what happens is "status" is assign the number of characters.` do you say that read() method will read the content of the file in blocks of 65536 ? Is that how it works ??

Comment: Not quite. Read reads the file and returns the number of characters it read. Status is assigned that. Read also puts the characters into the buffer. See the javadoc for more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: so say for example the file has 10 characters and the read() will read one character at a time by the java documentation. Now the status will be valid until it reads the 10th character and the while is still valid so it reads the 11th character which is null. so in that case even if the read() puts in null into the buffer according to the original code it should remove only the first character but why is he losing the whole line ? correct me if i was wrong.. thanks!!

Comment: The line isn't actually lost. See @Peter's answer. The line is just overflowed because when read() is first called, it returns the number of characters read, which would be 10 with your example. Since 10 is the value of status, the while loop is satisfied. However, when read() is called again, since the reader is now at the last position, it returns -1. The next time through, the loop fails and the StringBuilder is printed. The reason why the first line is not displayed is because the line itself, because of how the loop has run, is 60000+ characters long, which won't be displayed in most IDEs

Comment: The whole reason for the loop is in case the file in larger than the buffer.